# In bootstrap 4, how to put media list inline?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a "media list" inline using Bootstrap 4. I use list-inline, but it is not work. How to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can find in the [Bootstrap 4 Documentation](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/typography/#inline), you need to add the `list-inline-item` class to child elements.

The new markup for `list-inline` is:

```
<ul class="list-inline">
  <li class="list-inline-item">Lorem ipsum</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Phasellus iaculis</li>
  <li class="list-inline-item">Nulla volutpat</li>
</ul>
```

Now they aren't directly adding styles to HTML elements, this way you can use these styles in other elements that aren't necessarily `<ul>`.